# Open a directory in a Linux GUI file browser via the command line

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to open a file browser window (in KDE or GNOME or some desktop environment) for a directory while your navigating directories from the terminal?

Text editors that have a GUI will open up when I run them via the command line; I just wanted to do that for certain directories when I'm roaming around.

Answer (score 12):

In Gnome you can do

`nautilus . &`

The dot means current directory, and the & runs the process in the background so you can continue to use your terminal (and ctrl+c won't kill the browser).

Comment: Just to help search engine users: if you're using Ubuntu, this probably applies to you.

Comment: It just works. Thanks. But remembering `nautilus .` is huge. So I added an alias in my .bashrc to `alias open='nautilus .'`.. Simple to remember. :)

Comment: if you want a solution that works with other desktop environments besides Gnome, use xdg-open as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 10):

`xdg-open .` This alone should do the trick if you want to open the current directory, else try `xdg-open /path`.

Answer (score 8):

```
xdg-open my_dir
```

Answer (score 2):

MacOS 10

Open current directory: `open .`

Comment: Nice. Works in KDE too.